# Code::Blocks and ROS Setup - rospack export returns empty line

Tags: catkin, ros-kinetic, rospack

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I'm trying to integrate Code::Blocks with the [actionlib_tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/actionlib_tutorials/Tutorials) package to no avail. I'm using the [ROS IDEs Wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/IDEs#CodeBlocks) page for Code::Blocks and I'm getting a blank line when using:

> rospack export --lang=cpp --attrib=cflags PackageName

> rospack export --lang=cpp --attrib=lflags PackageName

I've created the package using catkin tools and have successfully run *catkin build* in the package root.

My ROS_PACKAGE_PATH is:

> /TigerBotWS/TigerBot/src/actionlib_tutorials:/opt/ros/kinetic/share

And using tree on my package looks like the following:

> . ├── build
>
> │   ├── actionlib_tutorials
>
> │   └── catkin_tools_prebuild
>
> ├── devel
>
> │   ├── etc
>
> │   ├── lib
>
> │   └── share
>
> ├── logs
>
> └── src
>
> │   └── actionlib_tutorials

Any idea as to why the cflags attribute from rospack export might be blank?

Thanks in advance.

(P.S. There was a previous topic about this [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/190307/code-blocks-and-catkin-indigo/). The tutorial is points to did not solve my issue hence the re-post)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/257916/code::blocks-and-ros-setup---rospack-export-returns-empty-line/) by [brharper13](https://answers.ros.org/users/29746/brharper13/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-03-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I haven't used Code::Blocks before, so I am not sure if this creates your problem, but I am sure that your ROS_PACKAGE_PATH is not initialized correctly.

ROS_PACKAGE_PATH should point to the src folder of your workspace.
For correct initialization of this environment variable do:

```
source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash 
cd /TigerBotWS/TigerBot
catkin build
source devel/setup.bash
```

In addition, you could export these flags with the export tag of actionlib_tutorials/package.xml

---

Originally posted by [angeltop](https://answers.ros.org/users/29793/angeltop/) with karma: 351 on 2017-03-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0